# Find out last added UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I'd like to find out the last UITableViewCell in the last position of my UITableView and change the detailTextLabel of this cell into "Last added". Does someone knows how to do this in Swift?

Comment: We mean the last cell dequeued or the cell in the last position of your tableView?

Comment: in the last position of the tableview

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  The last *cell* added is effectively random and meaningless.  The last table row added is defined and controlled by you.

Comment: For example my tableview has 3 cells. In the first cell the label is "Apple". How can I find out the indexPath of the 3rd cell (last cell) and change it's detailTextLabel?

Comment: Ask your data source "What's the last row in the table?"  Your data source obviously needs to know that value, since it returns `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tableView gives you all you need to create last rows's indexPath and get it's cell.

```
let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections()-1
let lastSectionLastRow = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(lastSectionIndex) - 1
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:lastSectionLastRow, inSection: lastSectionIndex)
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

but depending on your needs you might be better accessing the cell in tableView's delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,  
    willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Something like

```
let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections()-1
let lastSectionLastRow = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(lastSectionIndex) - 1
let lastIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:lastSectionLastRow, inSection: lastSectionIndex)

let cellIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

if cellIndexPath == lastIndexPath {
    // the last cell is about to be displayed. change get here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I get an error at this line of code: `let lastIndexPath = NSIndexPath.indexPathForRow(lastSectionLastRow, inSection: lastSectionIndex)`. Error: `'indexPathForRow(_:inSelection:) is unavailable: use object construction 'NSIndexPath(forRow:inSelection:)'`

Comment: if `tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)` returns `nil`, you should use: 
`let cellIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(cell.center)`

Comment: if `tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)` returns `nil` you definitely **** something up and should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Since table views always require a datasource, you should look there instead of the table view.

```
NSIndexPath *lastCellIDP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.dataSource.lastObject inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *lastCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastCellIDP];
lastCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"U NEED 2 ChAnGE!";
```

That code assumes your datasource is of type `NSArray`.

That said, I would put this logic inside a `UITableViewCell` subclass when you bind the data, or possibly the property on your model of your datasource if it's the last item.